# How to make use ngModel.NgModelController's properties $touched within the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In fact, I want to ask how to make use `ngModel.NgModelController's` method and properties within the controller, and it will be perfect if there is more explaination about the usage of `ngModel.NgModelController` instead of giving the link of the `api` to me? What I have faced, is I want to set something like the following works within my controller. More precisely, I want to make the option with "--- please fill in ---" 's text to disappear once the droplist is clicked, but I want to do the operation at the controller instead of like the example below. To split off my question, there are several pieces I am interested in:

1. How do I set up the object used for the form (as I am doing a form) at both the controller and the HTML template
2. How do I set up the corresponding objects to each of the form field, like the select field below in both the controller and the HTML template
3. What else should I know to solve the question?

   ```
   <select name="dropdown"
             ng-model="$ctrl.value"
             ng-options="o.id as (o.state) for o in $ctrl.form.stateCode.options">
       <option ng-if="!form.dropdown.$touched" value=""> --- please fill in --- </option>
   </select>
   ```

P.S. I don't know whether because I am using `requireJS` together with `angular`, so the `$ctrl` may actually representing the scope of the controller.

Comment: Use the [ng-form Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) to bind the [ngModelController API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) to scope. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular when you are using forms it is more recommended that you should use form tag with a `name` attribute so that angular binds that form to the current controller scope. 
and after that when you are using input with in that form then the input that are using `ng-model` directive, that input controller will be bind to the `formcontroller`. Here I am attaching a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WdVDh/79/

`$ctrl` is not same as `$scope`. When we are using `controller as`  syntax, then angular binds the `$ctrl` property to the `$scope`

For more info on this you should go for https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms